# How to delete a ghost vault?

Tags: kubuntu

I created a vault and then I deleted it but it somehow went wrong(I don't remember what happened because it was very confuse) and now I have a "ghost" vault that I can't do anything with.

Answer (score 0):

Try first backing up, then editing the plasmavaultrc file in ~/.config/plasmavaultrc and removing the entire section that has the offending vault as the header in brackets, e.g. [/home/user/.local/share/unwanted.enc]

Then log out and in.